# react-bootstrap form switch button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js, react-bootstrap

I can't seem to figure out why I am not able to set the default value for react-bootstrap switch to false (off). It seems the only time the value will change is when I trigger the onChange event handler. Am I missing something? Here is the switch portion in my form:

```js
<Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3">
  <Col sm={10}>
    <Form.Check
      type="switch"
      id="custom-switch"
      label="Enable GTC"
      defaultChecked="false"
      onChange={(e) => setField('gtc', e.target.checked)}
    />
  </Col>
</Form.Group>
```

Here is how I am handling the state for the form.

```js
  const setField = (field, value) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [field]: value,
    });
  };
```

I would think `defaultChecked="false" would do the trick but it does not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First

```
const [switchState, setSwitchState] = useState(false);
```

then assign the :

```
defaultChecked={switchState}
```

Now write the change handler function

```
const handleChange=(e)=>{
   setField('gtc', e.target.checked)
   setSwitchState(!switchState)
    
}
```

final code:

```
<Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3">
  <Col sm={10}>
    <Form.Check
      type="switch"
      id="custom-switch"
      label="Enable GTC"
      defaultChecked={switchState}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  </Col>
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `defaultChecked="false"`. By having it as a prop, `defaultChecked` is set to true.

Comment: I tried that but true or false isn't assigned until I actually toggle to button switch.

Comment: When a checkbox is unchecked it's value is not submitted. Value also doesn't change, it's just a string. You could create an hidden checkbox with the same name and have it checked with a "false" value or you could have gtc set to false in your inital state.

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultChecked={false}` instead. The value should be a boolean, rather than a string.

However, the answer posted by @Yilmaz is the full solution.